# How to find source of traffic to /socket.io on Win 10 desktop

Tags: windows-10, network-traffic

I've noticed that when I run a local web server for web app development, the logs show that something is consistently trying to GET `/socket.io` from localhost on port 3000. Typically, I'm seeing this when running puma, inside a Docker container, as the local server for a Rails app. However, I tried running a simple local server using node (http-server, one page) and the logs show the same traffic, so it doesn't appear to necessarily be Docker related, it's just constant traffic coming from somewhere.

Reboot the machine and it doesn't show up immediately, but eventually that traffic starts up again. I've tried shutting down background apps to see if it's one of those, to no avail. My laptop is configured similarly to my desktop wrt Docker and Hyper-V and such, and it doesn't happen on the laptop.

Clearly, there's something running on the machine that is doing this, but I can't find it. What else can I do to try and figure out where it's coming from?

Samples:

In the Rails app log:

`Started GET "/socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560455293858-21046" for 172.18.0.1 at 2019-06-13 19:48:13 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/socket.io"):`

In a simple node http-server one-pager:

`[Thu Jun 13 2019 16:15:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] "GET /socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560456944267-21720" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.30 Safari/537.36 NVIDIACEFClient/rel_03_17/c6b7277 NVIDIAOSCClient/3.17.0.126"
[Thu Jun 13 2019 16:15:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] "GET /socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560456944267-21720" Error (404): "Not found"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;dr:** *turn off the **In Game Overlay** feature in **NVIDIA GeForce Experience**. Install/reinstall latest drivers, if necessary.*

So, based on [this observation from mtlynch](https://superuser.com/a/1457426/99586), I started my docker container and web app and watched the traffic while I messed around with NVIDIA stuff.

I stopped the GeForce Experience app - no discernible change.

I then started ending NVIDIA processes through **Task Manager**. I had several: `NVIDIA Container`, `NVIDIA Share`, `NVIDIA Webhelper`, etc. Stopping the `NVIDIA Share` processes (there were three) did the trick - when I whacked the last of these the incessant pinging on `socket.io` stopped immediately.

Some subsequent searching around with new keywords brought me to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/343120/what-are-all-those-nvidia-processes-running-in-the-background/):

> If you do want to disable some NVIDIA processes, toggling the “In-Game
>   Overlay” off in GeForce Experience is a guaranteed safe way to do it.
>   This will get rid of the NVIDIA ShadowPlay Helper process and the two
>   NVIDIA Share processes until you turn it back on. Again, we don’t
>   generally recommend disabling services from the Services menu—using
>   the program’s built-in options is generally a safer way to cut down on
>   these running processes.

When I rebooted and tried to open GeForce Experience to test this out, I got an error - I couldn't even get the application to open. Perhaps this was ultimately part of the problem, no telling at this point.

I ended up removing and installing the latest NVIDIA driver, at which point I was able to open GeForce Experience and turn the **In Game Overlay** feature on/off. Sure enough, the `NVIDIA Share` processes stopped when I turned that feature off, and when they are stopped there is no more pinging to socket.io on localhost from NVIDIA.

Answer (score 3):

The user agent contains:

> NVIDIACEFClient/rel_03_17/c6b7277 NVIDIAOSCClient/3.17.0.126

I'm having the same issue, and I believe it's coming from NVIDIA GeForce tools, but I can't figure out how to stop GeForce from spamming localhost:3000.

Comment: Crazy - I hadn't even noticed that - good catch! I will investigate and respond if I find anything on it.